# How to dismiss segue ios8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uistoryboardsegue

I am not much familiar with segue. I have used it for very first time.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegue" sender:nil];

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    id destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    if ([destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[MFSideMenuContainerViewController class]])
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:Main bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:NavigationController];
        MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)destinationViewController;
        UIViewController *leftSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:LeftSideMenuIdentifier];

        [container setLeftMenuViewController:leftSideMenuViewController];
        [container setCenterViewController:navigationController];
    }
}
```

My problem is while I am trying to dismiss it on LOGOUT button which is in SideMenu using below method,

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Nothing is happening. Don't know how to dismiss it.
Can anyone have solution for this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look for unwind segues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:) `dismissViewControllerAnimated`

> Dismisses the view controller that was presented modally by the
>   receiver.

So this works for modally presented controllers, for navigation stacks, use [unwind segues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them) instead.

Comment: My ViewController presented modally. Still it's not working. I also don't know why?

Answer (score 1):

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Above statement dismisses a view controller when a view controller is present.

If you are using "PUSH" or "SHOW", then your view controller is pushing to navigation stack. Well in that case you have to POP that view controller from the navigation stack.

Try below code

```
[self.navigationController popViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I am using "MODAL", my view controller is presenting on login button. So [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; must be worked. But it's not :(